# Macro to find underlined words, freezes Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that I would like to use to pull out all underlined words in a Word Document, and save them somewhere. I have tried saving to .txt and .xlsx, and it freezes both times.

Here's my code:

```
Sub addUnderlinedWordsToArray_2()
Dim thisDoc As Word.Document, rngXe As Word.Range
Dim aRange  As Range
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim myWords() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim bFound As Boolean

i = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set thisDoc = ActiveDocument
Set aRange = thisDoc.Content
Set rngXe = aRange.Duplicate
bFound = True

With aRange.Find
  '  .ClearFormatting
'    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
    .Font.Underline = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
End With

Do While bFound
    bFound = aRange.Find.Execute
    If bFound Then
        Set rngXe = aRange.Words(1)
        'aRange.Select
        If bFound Then
            If Len(aRange) > 1 Then
                If Not aRange.InRange(thisDoc.TablesOfContents(1).Range) Then
                   aRange.MoveEndWhile cset:=Chr(13), Count:=wdBackward
                   ReDim Preserve myWords(i)
                   myWords(i) = aRange.Text
                   i = i + 1
                   aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
'                   Debug.Print "Page: " & aRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Loop

Set aRange = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

I've stepped through it a lot, and I never get thrown an error.  It *is* working though, since I can see the array being populated.  With the code above, I planned on first getting it to work, then pass the `myWords()` array into another sub that will just put them in a .txt file, line by line.

Full disclosure: I'm not sure if there are errors in that code, or not, but I have also asked about this in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136225/take-all-underlined-words-put-in-excel-column), as I thought the code works, just could be tweaked.  After playing with this, I'm not sure if the code actually works, so I'm asking here. I'm not sure what the rules are in double posting, so please let me know if this is not okay asking here too.

Comment: Until it stops freezing remove `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` so you can see what's happening or what dialog box is popping up

Comment: What do you mean when you say ". I have tried saving to .txt and .xlsx" - where in your code are you doing that?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions above, try running this code on a new document with only a few underlined words, to see if you get the same freeze. Then you could step through the whole thing to see where the hang occurs.

Comment: @dbmitch - I've simplified the code for this. I have a second sub to take the array, and put in .txt/.xlsx. If you click the "CodeReview" link I put in there, there's another method I tried as well, that includes the .xlsx info.

Comment: So you don't get any hangs when you step through it to completion on a tiny word doc?

Comment: If you haven't included the code that hangs, then your question is incomplete and tough to help you with. We aren't going to go back and forth between Code Review and here

Comment: @AndrewWynn - I'm doing that now, and will report back.

Comment: @dbmitch - no matter which one I use, it hangs. I'm using the above code though, since that only uses Word. I figure it is complicating things when I use Excel as well. The code posted in here, is the one I'm working with.

Comment: @AndrewWynn - So, I took my 100+ pg. document, and cut it to 30 pages. Ran the macro, it froze.  I then cut it to 10 pages, and it ran, no freezing.  I cut it to 17 pages, and again, it ran fine.  At 20 pages, it froze again. So, I put a stop when it gets to 17 pages, at which point I can hold `F8`, and it runs okay, no errors or freezing ...? What could be causing it to freeze when running 100% auto, but not when I stop it at a point, and continue "manually"?

Comment: maybe the redim is causing a memory fault? and when you do it step by step, you are letting the memory freeing the memory unused by the previous array?

Comment: @gbianchi - That's good thinking. I think the crux of the matter is letting it run all on its own, it kind of "runs over itself"?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. I was able to identify 30,000 underlined words out of a total 140,000 words in about 25 seconds.

```
Sub addUnderlinedWordsToArray()
On Error GoTo errhand:
    Dim myWords()       As String
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim myDoc           As Document: Set myDoc = ActiveDocument ' Change as needed
    Dim aRange          As Range: Set aRange = myDoc.Content
    Dim sRanges         As StoryRanges: Set sRanges = myDoc.StoryRanges
    Dim ArrayCounter    As Long: ArrayCounter = 0 ' counter for items added to the array
    Dim Sentence        As Range
    Dim w               As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ReDim myWords(aRange.Words.Count) ' set a array as large as the
                                      ' number of words in the doc

    For Each Sentence In myDoc.StoryRanges
        For Each w In Sentence.Words
            If w.Font.Underline <> wdUnderlineNone Then
                myWords(ArrayCounter) = w
                ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

   'Do something with the array here
   'It's not needed to resize the array, just
   'use for i = Lbound(MyWords) to ArrayCounter-1 
   'this will save a redim preserve, alternatively
   'just select up to ArrayCounter-1 if you are moving to an Excel Range

    'Clean up
    Set myDoc = Nothing
    Set aRange = Nothing
    Set sRange = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

errhand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Subroutine Name: addUnderlinedWordsToArray" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
End Sub
```